# Closed form of a simple series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closed form with of a series Mathematica](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161517/closed-form-with-of-a-series-mathematica)

I've this series, and I don't find with Mathematica any simplification. Someone has any idea how to get a closed form?

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x+kx_0-h}{|x+kx_0|^3}$$

Thanks!